# Give internet access with a not VLAN enabled router to two VLAN networks

Tags: vlan, hp-procurve

I'm a bit of a novice in this area. I currently have two VLAN-capable switches (HP ProCurve <s>2850</s> 2824) and some switches and routers that are not VLAN-capable, more like consumer-level devices (such as POE switches for cameras and remote APs). My goal is to separate different networks. I have the hardware but I need to understand the theory a little bit more before trying to do this.
To simplify the question, let's assume I only have two VLAN-capable switch (lets call them HP1 e HP2) and a router.

I'll connected all the PC of VLAN 1  to HP1 ports and configure them as "*untagged VLAN_1*" and all the PC of VLAN 2 to HP2 ports and configure them as "*untagged VLAN_2*"

Then I can
-option A, connect the two switches between them and configure these 2 ports as "*tagged VLAN_1 & tagged VLAN_2*", then connect HP1 to the router and I think I should set the eth port as untagged as the router seems not to support VLANs, bue then if is "*untagged*" I can set only onle VLAN, and so if I'll configure it as "*untagged VLAN_1*" no one from VLAN_2 will be able to access internet

-option B, connect HP1 to the router, setting the eth port as "*untagged VLAN_1*" and HP2 to another port of the router setting eth port as "*untagged VLAN_2*".
In this configuration, both devices from VLAN_1 and VLAN_2 will be able to reach the router and so to go online, but all traffic from VLAN_1 will be stripped of VLAN identifiers once exiting from the port connected to router, and will be tagged as VLAN_2 when re-entering from the router from the port connected to HP2.
So the two VLANs will not be separated.

Are my suppositions true, both for option A and option B?
Is there any way to achieve VLAN separation AND internet access with the previous mentioned hardware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Connecting a VLAN to a device without tagging support requires a dedicated, untagged port ("access").
- In reverse, a device without VLAN support can only use a single, untagged VLAN on each port.
- Routing between VLANs requires either a layer-3 switch (like an HPE 2824), or a router which multiple routed ports (VLAN subinterfaces on a VLAN-capable router).
- You can configure a single (trunk) port for multiple, tagged VLANs between VLAN-capable switches or routers.
- If you bridge between different VLANs, then they effectively become one.
- Off-topic consumer-grade routers often have multiple "LAN" ports, but those are actually switched and cannot be configured separately. Most consumer routers can only route between a single WAN and all LAN ports. Most cannot deactivate NAT for IP4.

Your easiest option is to use a 2824 as a layer-3 switch (`ip routing`) that can be used for routing between VLANs. If you want to separate different security zones the switch also requires (extended) ACL support for restricting traffic.

[image]

With an L3 switch, you'd set your clients' default gateway to the respective switch VLAN/virtual interface (SVI), and the switch's default route via the router's private IP. On the router, you'd add a static route, e.g. for 192.168.0.0/16 via the L3 switch's VLAN interface.

On the switch you could then freely create VLANs with subnets from 192.168.0.0/16 (e.g. 192.168.10.0/24, 192.168.11.0/24, ...) and configure ACLs to limit each VLAN's access to the other VLANs or the Internet.

The 2800 switch series is pretty aged (retired in 2009)  and has no IPv6 support - so there's no v6 routing between VLANs or v6 ACLs.

Comment: Thanks Zac67, I made a typing error, my two switches are HP Procurve 2824 and therefore should have some Layer3 routing capabilities.
So if I understand correctly I will need to connect the modem/router to one of the switches on a "untagged VLAN_3" port to achieve separation from both VLAN_1 e VLAN_2, then use the ip routing to let VLAN_1 communicate with VLAN_3 and VLAN_2 communicate with VLAN_3.

Comment: Yes, that'll work, just don't forget the static route on the router. 2824 and 2848 are the same except for port count.